Image size in bytes increases two times after export
This question appears in the process of investigation bug report on MSE.
I created a screenshot on iPad by swiping from the left bottom corner and saved it in photo section.
iPad says that the image size of this screenshot on device is 1.3Mb, screenshot from standard iPadOS image application:



At the same time when I try to export it as file (i.e. without any conversion), the size is increased to 2.8Mb:



What's the real image size? Why are the sizes different?
My device: iPad Pro 11" Gen 3, iPadOS 17.4.1

How was the PNG file originally created? It's likely that the OS saves it using particular compression levels that may be different from the origin.

@benwiggy it's a screenshot. Added that info to the post body.

Does it recursively happen, if you export the exported copy?

@benwiggy I'm not sure what you mean. What steps should I do to export exported copy?

Do the same thing again with the exported copy. Export it from Photos.

@benwiggy if I save that data as image from Telegram back into the device gallery the resulting file appears in JPEG format. If I store it as file it is still PNG in Files app. Looks like there's some implicit conversion on export (from gallery to Telegram) even in file mode.
